# Application's associated file (JNLP) does not have a digital signature

Tags: java, security, certificate, jnlp

I have a unique problem with web start certificate pop up.
- We generate our jnlp file on the fly when a user request comes in handled by a special Jnlp servlet we wrote that provides parameter values at runtime.
- These parameters are read in from the jnlp file as system property later by the client.

So the actual jnlp that is dynamically generated is not signed but rest all of the jars/resources are signed properly.

[image]

[image]

But we get this annoying pop up warning that not all the resources of this application are signed and upon clicking on details the message is this:

"Although the application has a digital signature, the application's associated file (JNLP) does not have one. A digital signature ensures that a file is from the vendor and that it has not been altered."

Has anyone seen this and is there way to handle this?

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Add signing to your generation process.  It is part of the "fix the security issues in Java" makeover which has happened in the last years.

Comment: Our jars files are already singed and verified still having the same issue.

Comment: According to "Although the application has a digital signature, the application's associated file (JNLP) does not have one. A digital signature ensures that a file is from the vendor and that it has not been altered." the JNLP file also needs to be signed.

Comment: A small confirmation. The trusted certificate has been generated using JDK6 keytool utility, will that certificate works on JDK7 environment.

Comment: I don't know.  Consider opening a new question.  You probably also need to read up on how to sign the JNLP file, so you can do it on the fly.